# return back multiple levels in nested functions

Tags: python-2.7

I have

```
def myfunc():
    if something_happens:
        return_handler()
    more_code
    if something_happens:
        return_handler()
    even_more_code


def return_handler():
   standardized finish up code
   return*2  # drops out of not just return_handler but also the calling function, e.g. myfunc
```

I would like return*2 in `return_handler` to force not just `return_handler` but also `myfunc` to finish. I have a number of `return`s in `myfunc` based on various situations, and each time there is some standardized finish up code that needs to run. Rather than have to paste the same code in each place, I'd like to move that into `return_handler`.

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Right now you are neither passing arguments nor returning anything. What handle are you talking about?

Comment: I would recommend Googling 'python returning from functions' and 'python calling a function' before posting here.

Comment: If u look at it, when the meth1() executes it calls meth2() which in-turn calls meth3(). After the execution of the meth3(), the program handle comes to meth2() and executes "statement in meth2". I want the program handle to return to meth1() and not execute "statement in meth2"

Comment: So put in a `return` statement before `statement in meth2` or remove `statement in meth2`. You can have `return` anywhere in a function. In fact, since Python is not strongly typed, you can have different `return`s returning totally different types of things.

Comment: I am not sure that "handle" is the right word. Not sure what the right word is though.

Comment: :), where do i put the return statement?

Comment: Edited my comment. You should really read some Python docs. This question shows remarkably little effort on your part.

Comment: :), thanks, I did not put the question in a right way I guess...

Answer (score 0):

If immediately after calling `return_handler` you are always going to `return` back out of `myfunc` as well, then instead of just calling `return_handler` you can simply do:

```
return return_handler()
```

This will run `return_handler` and then `return` whatever `return_handler` happened to `return` (which will be `None` if nothing was returned).